# how to perform cold-boot & warm-boot by C# code on windows-mobile 5.0?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-5.0

How to perform cold-boot & warm-boot using C# for Windows Mobile 5.0?

and is there any program that can run command prompt on windows-mobile 5.0 ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]

        public static extern int KernelIoControl(int dwIoControlCode, IntPtr lpInBuf, int nInBufSize, IntPtr lpOutBuf, int nOutBufSize,ref int lpBytesReturned);

        private int CTL_CODE(int DeviceType, int Func, int Method, int Access)

        {           

           return (DeviceType << 16) | (Access << 14) | (Func << 2) | Method;

        }
        private int ResetPocketPC()

        {
            const int FILE_DEVICE_HAL = 0x101;

            const int METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;

            const int FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;

            int bytesReturned = 0;

            int IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT;

            IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_HAL, 15, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);

            return KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref bytesReturned);

        }
```

More informations and how to use the code can be obtained from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/restartwidnowsmobile.aspx). There is another great article about this at [Psion Cummunity Blog](http://community.psion.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/how-to-programmatically-warm-reset-cold-reset-and-boot-into-boost.aspx), that I highly recommend you to check out too.